Powershell Invoke-WebRequest returns "code":-1002,"description":"Cannot parse message body"
I am trying to add a new domain using the Sectigo API.
The following code returns the error
Invoke-WebRequest : { "code":-1002, "description": "Cannot parse message body"}
$domain = Read-Host "Provide Domain name" 
$crt_domain = '"{`"name`":`"' + $domain + '`",`"description`":`"Domain created via REST API`",`"active`":true,`"delegations`":[{`"orgId`":000000,`"certTypes`":[`"SSL`"]}]}"'

$create_domain = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://cert-manager.com/api/domain/v1" `
    -Method Post `
    -Headers $headers `
    -ContentType "application/json;charset=utf-8" `
    -Body $crt_domain

If I replace the $crt_domain to classic sting in Invoke Request then it is working
$create_domain = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://cert-manager.com/api/domain/v1" `
    -Method Post `
    -Headers $headers `
    -ContentType "application/json;charset=utf-8" `
    -Body "{`"name`":`"google.com`",`"description`":`"Domain created via REST API`",`"active`":true,`"delegations`":[{`"orgId`":000000,`"certTypes`":[`"SSL`"]}]}"

During other API connection method used in the first case works properly.
I would appreciate some guidance. Beginner API user.

You might simply use a hashtable for the -body parameter: $crt_domain = @{ name = $domain; description = "..." }

You're using single quotes around the string you assign to $crt_domain, so the powershel escape sequence  " "  is being treated as a literal string and appears verbatim in $crt_domain - try doing write-host $crt_domain and see what the result is. By comparison, your second code snippet uses double quotes around the -Body parameter value, so the " " is parsed as just a double-quote. However, the best solution is to use a hashtable per @iRon's comment above - you'll get syntax colouring and warnings in the IDE then.
